# AngularJS's ng-model does not bind selected value from drop-down menu (ng-options), also unable to reload page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-options

Basically, I have a web server running on localhost, and I want to exchange data between my AngularJS web app and my server. I successfully transfer the data, but displaying it properly is a problem.

I've made a simplified plunkr version of my  [AngularJS application...](http://plnkr.co/edit/tOU9M0hfQwRt2tYZFC6E)

Obviously, you don't have the server side code, but you do not need it.
As said in plunkr i have more than one problem:

- I can't reload page using `$route.reload()`, I also tried with `$window.location.reload(true)`, `$window.location.href = $window.location.href`... nothing worked so far
- Also, ng-model in ng-options doesn't bind data. If I enter debugger when calling sendData, tempData is defined but selectedListItem is not (even though I selected a value from drop-down menu)

Any advice is more than welcome,

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You don't use routes, that's why $route.reload doesn't work.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to set the listItem object as the select list value - this should be a value (int, string etc).  Is there an Id on listItem you can use?

e.g.

ng-options="listItem.Id as (listItem.text1 + ' ' + listItem.text2 + ' ' + listItem.text3 + ' ' + listItem.text4) for listItem in tempData.listItems"

$scope.selectedListItem = data.listItems[0].Id;

Comment: dfsq: Can you explain how to use routes, or send me a link to a tutorial?

@Tom Yes, there is a value I can use as an ID, I'll try and report back.
Thanks to both of you

Comment: Just curious: why do you want to reload your view?

Comment: @Tom I want to empty all the data on the page... I know it can be done using forms with form.setPristine() and setting ng-models to default values, but I haven't had time to fiddle with that just yet. I did try it, but had problem with dropdown menu keeping the last selected value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the 3 problems you mention:

#### 1.Page reload doesn't work

You can't use `$route.reload()` if you are not using `ngRoute` and you haven't configured any routes.
(BTW, adding `ngRoute` as a dependency, while not including the relevant JS script will raise errors.)

---

#### 2. `ngModel` doesn't bind data to `selectedListItem`

This seems to work as expected once you fix the other errors (see demo below).

---

#### 3. Can't set dropdown menu to default value

This seems to work as expected once you fix the other errors (see demo below).

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/ezzQrIuLjMTYlT2FoYO4?p=preview)**.

Comment: Thank you for the working demo... Looks like one of the problems was also .css from template I bought. After removing it and corresponding .js everything worked like a charm ;)
$window.location.reload() works on Firefox, but not on Chrome, probably due to another .css. Anyway, since data binding works now, I don't need to reload the page, just set forms to their pristine state, and models to their default value

Answer (score 1):

See the AngularJS tutorial on routing and views:

https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

Comment: Thank you for the info... since all the problems have been resolved I don't think I'll be using routes, but it's good to know where to find a tutorial if I need one ;)